# What does the motion of water in tsunamis look like?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, waves, water, solitons, tsunami

This is what normal wave motion looks like.
[image]

Do tsunamis that travel at 60mph look any different?

Comment: This looks like a good question for [SE.EarthScience](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/14688/

Comment: Out on the ocean, tsunamis have much higher speeds, like that of jet liner, 600 mph.

Answer (score 1):

The period of a tsunami is long (say about 30 minutes), so the wavelength of that wave is about 30 miles, much longer than the depth of the deep ocean (about 3 km).

And out on the ocean, speed is like that of a jet liner, about 800 km/h.

So tsunamis are shallow water waves, with a speed given by $v= \sqrt{g \lambda}$, even in the deep ocean.